# People picker not working in classic mode web application in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, peoplepicker

I have a SharePoint 2010 web application migrated to SharePoint 2013. this is a classic mode web application, we are not using claims, my client doesn't wants it ( Don't ask why?).
I had other web application migrated as same process but i can add users in them.
but in this i am not able to. 
I can add users and find users in the web application in central administration. But not in the web application itself.

I am not sure what changes i have to make so that it starts picking or finding users from the people picker. any ideas.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a browser compatible issue as well whereas in new browser like IE 10 and other latest browsers it doesn't play well.

we updated the
 In short the fix is to edit the pickerdialog.master file in notepad and add a meta data tag, ,  to the header section.

well keep in mind always save  a local copy of your original master page. 
it is recommended not to update any original files, we can run the site in compatible mode too.

Answer (score 1):

it was because of the asp.netvalidation=2.0 not present in the httprequest line in webconfig. there was no validation for the input provided in any input box. 
once we added the asp.net validation it worked fine.